# Want user to enter only Letter on Console.ReadLine();

Tags: c#

In C#, how can I restrict user to enter only text example (a to z) letters? only

```
namespace ConsoleApplication14
{
    class Program
    {
        public void studentProfile()
        {
            Dictionary<string, int> satya = new Dictionary<string, int>();
            {
                satya.Add("Acpl", 2);
                satya.Add("Bio", 1);
                satya.Add("Ch", 4);
                satya.Add("Om", 5);
            }

            Dictionary<string, int> rahul = new Dictionary<string, int>();
            {
                rahul.Add("Acpl", 2);
                rahul.Add("Bio", 1);
                rahul.Add("Ch", 4);
                rahul.Add("Om", 5);
            }
        }

        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            int maxAttempts = 5;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Did you know about Console.ReadKey?

Answer (score 2):

You have to read what they type and reject it if you don't like what they entered.

```
string input;
do
{
    input = Console.ReadLine();
} while (input.Any(c => !char.IsLetter(c)));
```